# Looking back at work you want to change but its gone to print?

Tags: print-design, design-principles, designers

I have recently just started at a new company as an art worker. (My first ever artworker job) I get given small jobs which require quick turn arounds. The other day I had to add some copy to a poster which is 3x3meters. However me being the worrier I am I decided to log onto my work email and check it out again. I've notice some of the copy isn't aligned. (i.e. the copy next to the twitter logo wasn't aligned in the middle, its about by a cm or so) I am now worrying and kicking myself in the teeth for a stupid mistake. It has now been sent to print. How do other designers deal with this when they look back and realised something so small would of made a big difference?

I seem to have become more of a perfectionist than ever since starting in the design industry.

Thanks,
Char

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is almost impossible to perform an artwork which will be 100% perfect, especially, when one's experience is limited and most of imperfections are typical to starters. This is why when I want to press "Send" button I take a break of 10 minutes or so and refresh my mind - after that I re-look at the work and almost always find something to improve - it can be endless actually, but somewhen I have to stop and push the Button.

The good thing - to learn from your and others mistakes and try to minimize them in your next work.

The second good thing - most of small inaccuracies do not catch the eye, thus there is the probability you will be the only person who knows about the mistake. If you think the mistake is not critical - let it go and do not do it again. Everyone did a lot of mistakes - this is the base of a learning.